# How to run Django code saved inside Model instances?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm using a custom Django (v1.5.5) model `Widget` used to contain HTML code (using a `TextField`) to be placed in certain places of different pages and allow staff users change the contents easily through the Django admin backend.

This approach works perfectly with HTML, CSS and Javascript code. Using the following syntax at the templates:

```
{{ widget.content|safe }}
```

However, I'd also like to be able to put Django code (using templatetags, calling methods...) within it, but this Django code does NOT get executed and instead it's directly printed as if it was plain text.

Is there any way to execute Django code using the `safe` filter? Or am I missing another filter? Maybe I'd have to use a custom filter or templatetag... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @sk1p's answer, I've created a Django `simple_tag` that takes an HTML string (which can contain "Django code") and the `context` (which is absolutely necessary here). Then I just render it and return. That's it!

I created a file called `smart_html.py` that contains:

```
from django import template
from django.template import Template


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_html(context, html):
    return Template(html).render(context)
```

Then, from the templates I just have to do:

```
{% load smart_html %}
{% render_html widget.content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have a template tag/filter like that by default. I'm using this in one of my projects:

```
class IncludeString(ttag.Tag):
    template_src = ttag.Arg()

    def render(self, context):
        data = self.resolve(context)
        try:
            t = loader.get_template_from_string(data['template_src'])
        except Exception, e:
            return u"error rendering template: %s" % unicode(e)
        return t.render(context)

    class Meta:
        name = "include_string"

register.tag(IncludeString)
```

And use it like `{% include_string variable_name_with_template_content %}`. This implementation uses [django-ttag](http://pythonhosted.org/django-ttag/), but I think something like the following should work, too (untested):

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_string(context, template_src):
    try:
        t = loader.get_template_from_string(template_src)
        return t.render(context)
    except Exception, e:
        return u"error rendering template: %s" % unicode(e)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sk1p! I've been able to find a really KISS solution based on what you explained. +1 :)